# Can't use Count() in C#

Tags: c#, linq, count, asp.net-core

I have a project using .NET CORE, and my controller has System.Linq already. Somehow I still have error when trying to use Count().

```
using xxx.Core;
using xxx.DataAccess;
using xxx.DataAccess.Azure;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace xxx.Api.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ResourcesController : Controller
    {
         private static DocumentDB _db = new DocumentDB();

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public IActionResult Get(string id)
        {
             using (var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(_db))
             {
                 var r = unitOfWork.Resources.Get(id);

                 Models.resource result =  ConvertResourceModel(r);

                 if (result.Count() != 1)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    return Ok(result);
                }
            }
        }
```

The line of if (result.Count() != 1) has an error on Count() said "resource does not contain a definition for Count and no extension method Count accepting the a first argument of type resource..." My resource model defined like below:

```
public class resource
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public List<translations> translations { set; get; }
    public DateTime modified { get; set; }
    public DateTime accessed { get; set; }
    public string by { get; set; }


}

public class translations {
    public string language { set; get; }
    public string content { set; get; }
    public DateTime modified { get; set; }
    public DateTime accessed { get; set; }
    public string by { get; set; }

}
```

I'm not sure why. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: `result` is of type `resource`, which doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`. What would you expect `Count` to return?

Comment: Where have you defined a method called `Count()` on the `resource` class?  (Hint: You haven't defined any methods on the `resource` class.)  What exactly are you trying to "count"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your resource is not a list but an object. Better implementation would be something like this.

```
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Get(string id)
    {
         using (var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(_db))
         {
             var r = unitOfWork.Resources.Get(id);

             if (r == null)
             {
                return NotFound();
             }

             return Ok(ConvertResourceModel(r));
        }
    }
```